# How Do I Mock MSAL Authentication?

Tags: javascript, authentication, mocking, msal.js, react-aad-msal

I have added authentication to my web app using MSAL which connects to Azure Active Directory B2C.

This works fine when I am connected and can access the Microsoft site. However, it fails when I am not.

e.g. on a plane or in a firewalled build server

How do I add mock authentication so that I can develop offline?

Comment: Refer this. You will be able to mock MSAL for local development
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62560239/13790754